# Is there a notion of pseudo convexity such that "$\Phi$ pseudoconvex $\iff \Phi'$ pseudomonotone" holds?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, monotone-functions

In our lecture we have proven the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $\Phi: V \to \mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is a real (reflexive) Banach space, possess the Gâteaux derivative $A: V \to V^*$.
>   Then $\Phi$ is convex iff $A$ is monotone.

We call an operator pseudomonotone if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $V$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - u \rangle$ implies that $\langle Au, u -w \rangle \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - w \rangle$ holds for all $w \in V$.

Is there a notion of pseudo convexity (I understand there are multiple definitions) such that we can write pseudomonotone instead of monotone and pseudoconvex instead of convex?